# HTML5 pattern to check paired single quotes/double quotes/braces

Tags: regex, html, validation

I am struggling with the HTML5 pattern attribute to validate a form field whose input can be of the below listed types.

- stackoverflow,stackexchange,google,search-engine
- stackoverflow,stackexchange,'google search',search-engine,"Barrack Obama"
- Maharastra (Mumbai-400060),stackexchange,'google search',search-engine,"Barrack Obama"

I have used the pattern attribute [A-Za-z0-9'"-()]{1-250}
But unable to validate the paired quotes or braces.

Any help is highly appreciated

Jay Chakra

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you need help with. You need a regex that'll match stuff like `stackoverflow`, `search-engine`, `'google search'`, but not `'google search"`, or `"Obama`?

Comment: No I want a looking for a regex which can match all these criteria including paired brackets and quotes.

The regex should be true for above cases but should be false for these cases

   stack'overflow,stackexchange,google,search-engine

   stackoverflow,stackexchange,'google search',search-engine,"Barrack Obama""

   Maharastra (Mumbai-(400060),stackexchange,'google search',search-engine,"Barrack Obama"


That is odd no of quotes or bad brackets closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the fundamental restrictions of regular expressions that you cannot handle paired  characters. You need a full grammar for this.

Basically, you would need a recursive rule similar to:

```
expression :- '(' expression ')'
           |  '{' expression '}'
           |  '"' expression '"'
           |  ...
```

So you would need to do this kind of validation in javascript itself instead.

Comment: Thanks manuBriot for the insight but I was trying to use HTML5 pattern attribute for the same.

Comment: No, you can do it without JavaScript. It would just be a very long regular expression using the pipe (|).  (?:pattern | pattern | pattern | ...)  etc.